# Custom Fonts src: url(/resource/disneyFont) "src : url " showing Error to add

Tags: css, custom, font

```
.THIS.HeaderFonts {
 font-family: 'GothamBold';
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'GothamBold';
   src : url(/resource/IRIS_CSS/assets/fonts/SanFranciscoProFonts/SF-Pro-Display-BlackItalic.otf);
}
```

Comment: Check this link http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/06/22/custom-font-lightning-component-static-resource/

Answer (score 0):

@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_bold.woff);
    font-weight: bold;
}